# CentOS Directory Owner

Tags: linux, centos5, chown

I have a dedicated CentOS 5.6 Server for our webhost. I've setup FTP account in PLESK to access our website. Once I migrated joomla over I can not change/modify or upload new files via: FTP. I've chmod'ed all necessary directory to 777 and 755 but still can't change or modify files.

I then noticed that the directory owner is displays nothing or 48 48.  How do I change the directory's ownership so I can upload and modify files to the FTP users account or did I do something wrong something completely.

Comment: `chown`.  Research also reveals that you might need to contact support if you're using a hosting company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ chown -R <username>:<group> /path/to/directory
```

Comment: Note that using a dot as delimiter is deprecated to allow for usernames to have a dot. You should instead use a colon (chown -R user:group /path/to/dir   - the dot still works on e.g. RHEL, but it does not on SLES.

Comment: Good point. Fixed.